# Trying to redirect using .htaccess but the site returns a 500 response

Tags: .htaccess

I have been trying to redirect all pages except one in my web to a new website using .htaccess code. I have been trying to use this .htaccess setting below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/test/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now the problem is everytime I saved the .htaccess, the site returns a 500 response code. Here is the site's full .htaccess code.

```
# Enable rewrite engine and route requests to framework
RewriteEngine On

# Some servers require you to specify the `RewriteBase` directive
# In such cases, it should be the path (relative to the document root)
# containing this .htaccess file
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

# Default expires header if none specified (stay in browser cache for 10 days)
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/css A864000
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A864000
    ExpiresByType image/gif A864000
    ExpiresByType image/png A864000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A864000
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A864000
</IfModule>
```

From what I have seen is that the current one is already having a Rewrite engine on. I have tried deleting all the original .htaccess and pasting the new one but the site returns a 404 not found response.

Any solution, Stackoverflow folks? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for adding your efforts, please post sample urls which are not working in your question, thank you.

Comment: Hi Ravinder, here is the site I mentioned above: indonesia.dune-network.com

Comment: So only this url is giving 404 OR there are others also.

Comment: all other URLs in the web is giving a 404

Comment: ok please do let me know what is the path of your htaccess file and what is the exact path of your php/css etc files in apache server?

Comment: That is the thing. I have no idea how the previous developer built the website. The paths shown in the frontend does not really exist in the backend.

Comment: Well, that's how it works in htaccess environment. Its made for that NEVER show outside users your actual path. So you need to may be look for where are you actual content residing eg: index.php OR any other php files. If you are using Linux/Unix O.S then you can `find` command on `/` root level of it and can look for it because you are the one who could give this information, once this info is there we could try to figure it out.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/test/` - there is no space between the test string and the pattern here, could be that that caused your 500 already. (Although you should actually check the error log, instead of having us do guesswork.)

Comment: Hi CBroe, where can I check the error logs? there is none

Comment: Your http server writes log files. The most important one is the error log file. It always contains entries, except if you explicitly turned it off - which would be a strange thing to do. Check the http server's configuration for the exact location, typically something like `/var/log/httpd` or `/var/log/apache2` ...